# Twilio Device Cannot Be Connected : Twilio Js

Tags: ios, cordova, twilio, phonegap

I have an issue regarding Twilio Javascript SDK and stuck in a
 situation where the issue directly involve IOS and RTC support. Right
 now, i cannot connect the twilio device after device is ready. There
 is no error or anything to track/debug.

Constantly, running the `connection.status()` return back `connecting` always. I think the signaling system works when there is an incoming call but again, `connection.accept()` and status remain `connecting` like forever.

**Application Overview**

```
Cordova/Phonegap app
https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/client/releases/1.6.9/twilio.min.js
shim:https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-1.0.2.js
https://github.com/BasqueVoIPMafia/cordova-plugin-iosrtc
```

Possible reasons: Can this be directly CSP issue? or I have you setup configuration using STUN/TURN?

Let me know if you need any information. It's not going to resolve because there is no error just "connecting" status.

Comment: Can you try turning debugging on and see if that gives any more information. Pass `{ debug: true }` as the second argument to `new Device()`.

Comment: debug : true makes no difference.

Comment: Sorry, the debug information should be in the developer tools console. Can you see if there is any diagnostic logging that might apply to this issue?

Comment: hi philnash, i have got twilio official response Unfortunately the Twilio Client JS SDK is not supported to work on iOS, even with the PhoneGap adapter and webrtc shim.

Only the native libraries are supported to access Programmable Voice from iOS.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/voip-sdk/ios

Alex Chan
Twilio Customer Support
www.twilio.com

Comment: Ah, of course. You might try this cordova package that implements the same API but uses the native SDKs under the hood: https://www.npmjs.com/package/twilio-client-phonegap-plugin